How to add a custom extensions on Chrome Devtools Frontend bundle source code?

I took the devtools front-end source code from a place and packaged it (as shown above), in this source code, how do I add an extension to it? Like this(below)
Instead of installing an extension the usual way (dragging a folder into chrome to install it), I needed to register it in the source code, but I didn't know where to start.


There's no such thing. You can augment the source of devtools itself and add a panel to it or you can build your own Chromium you can add a "component extension".
